# Running memtest.exe from Windows 10 bootble USB

Tags: memory, usb-boot

I used a microsft tool to create a bootable Window 10 install USB.
The key contains memtest at:
"H:\boot\memtest.exe"
When I boot off the USB it goes into Windows 10 install - how can I run the memtest.exe?
I know there lots of ways to make a bootable memtest USB but I want to know how to use memtest on the existing bootable Windows 10 USB that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Setup, [you can press Shift+F10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/295116/description-of-the-windows-setup-function-keys) to get a command line window.

From there you can navigate to \boot and run memtest.

You may need to use trial and error to see which drive letter the USB key has been assigned.  This will vary depending on what partitions are on the internal drives.

Comment: Thanks.  A couple of points worth making: a. On my system there was a C:\ drive and a D:\ drive on a RAID PCIe card, and 2 x BR drives.  I expected to find the drive therefore at G or after.  The D:\ drive didn't mount however (probably because of RAID card) so the USB stick was mounted as D:\ - but took a while to work that out. b. The Windows 10 memtest doesn't like running on a windows 7 system and gives and error like "this version of memtest is not compatible with the version of windows..." not sure why that is as memtest should have jack to do with windows...